# Can I create dynamic grid view with code for each element in java?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to java, I was working on VB.NET but it's not suitable for my new project. 
 I'm trying to make a POS system and I want to ask about a specific thing. 
 If I have a DB table with 10 rows and I need to put them in 10 panels like a grid view,
 in vb.net I need to make the 10 panels and repeat the code for each one and use hide and show attributes which is exhausting specialty if the table has more rows.
In PHP, I just need to use foreach statement to display the whole table without repeating any codes.
So can I create a dynamic grid view in java? 
 And what exactly should I learn in java? 
 Thank you and sorry for my bad language.

[image]

Comment: Since this question is tagged `javafx`, use a `javafx.scene.layout.GridPane`.

Comment: thank you, but can i make one code and apply it on all grids using loops like php?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: i know how loops works, i mean if i have a 2 buttons that does the same thing but on different panels, can i write the code once or i need to write the code for each button

Comment: well, best way the demonstrate what you can/do is to provide a [mcve] that highlights where you are stuck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you're trying to do:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    grid.setVgap(15);
    grid.setHgap(15);

    buildGrid(grid, getPanelNames());

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Example App");
    primaryStage.show();

  }

  private void buildGrid(GridPane grid, List<String> panelNames) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (String name : panelNames) {
      Label label = new Label(name);
      Button btn = new Button("Click Me!");
      btn.setOnAction(event -> {
        event.consume();
        showAlert(grid.getScene().getWindow(), name);
      });

      VBox box = new VBox(10, label, btn);
      box.setPadding(new Insets(10));
      box.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
      box.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
      grid.add(box, col, row);

      if (++col > 3) {
        col = 0;
        row++;
      }
    }

  }

  private List<String> getPanelNames() {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 13)
        .mapToObj(i -> "Panel #" + i)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private void showAlert(Window owner, String panelName) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.initOwner(owner);
    alert.setTitle(panelName);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Hello from \"" + panelName + "\"!");
    alert.show();
  }

}
```

Comment: hmm .... in the mood ;)

Comment: Thank you alot! that's exatly what i was asking about